# Querying the DOM in Windows 8 Apps from within a method

Tags: javascript, dom, windows-8, winjs

I'm struggling with this even after reading the MSDN documentation and the following online guides:

[Codefoster](http://codefoster.com/post/2012/03/15/Selecting-Elements-in-a-Windows-8-HTML-App.aspx)

[Stephen Walter](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/02/23/metro-query-selectors.aspx)

I think my problem is easy to fix and that I just am thinking about something in the wrong way. Basically I am querying my web service and on success running the following method. I am then trying to bind the result to my listview. For now I am using a hardcoded value `publicMembers.itemlist`which has been declared at the top of the document just to make sure I can actually bind to the list before doing it with my query results. Ignore line 2 for now.

Success Method:

```
_lookUpSuccess: function xhrSucceed(Result) {
        var response = JSON.parse(Result.responseText);
        listView = document.querySelector("#termTest");
        ui.setOptions(listView, {
            itemDataSource: publicMembers.itemList,
            itemTemplate: document.querySelector(".itemtemplate"),
        })

     },
```

Now, instead of using `document.querySelector`, I have also tried with `WinJS.Utilities.id` and `WinJS.Utilities.query`, neither of which worked either.  This doesn't break my code and introduce an error but it doesn't bind to the listview either so I think I have an issue in querying the right DOM element.  However exactly the same code does work if I add it to the top of the script, it is only when I place it in this method that it stops working.

EDIT: Also to clarify, when I debug `publicMembers.itemList` is storing the values I expect them to be.

Please point out if I have explained things poorly and I will try and improve my question.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to access listView.winControl, not just the element. Doing that and everything should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used WinJS.UI.setOptions, but rather this other way of setting the data source. Can you see if it works?

```
_lookUpSuccess: function xhrSucceed(result) {
    var response = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
    listView = document.querySelector("#termTest");

    listView.winControl.itemDataSource = publicMembers.itemList;
 },
```

This would assume you're defining the itemTemplate as part of the `data-win-options` attribute of your ListView's HTML element. You could also probably just do `listView.winControl.itemTemplate = document.querySelector(".itemtemplate")` if you prefer to set it programmatically.

Comment: I haven't actually been able to verify your answer yet, but I managed to fix my issue. After hours of debugging it seems that all I needed to do was add `var` before `listview`. I was making quite a few other tweaks but does this sound like a logical fix? I can't be certain it wasn't one of the other tweaks.

Comment: Not sure, but make sure you're specifying "use strict" in your code. This would have generated an error/warning for using a variable without declaring it.
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230269.aspx